# `docker services ls` shows running services but `docker ps -a` is missing running containers? Where are the other missing running containers listed?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

The wordpress service is running confirmed by `docker service ls` and the blog is up when visiting the blog url (which gets taken down after executing `docker stack rm wordpress`).

Once wordpress is deployed using `docker stack deploy` the stack looks like this:

```
user@prod:~/wordpress$ docker service ls
ID             NAME                  MODE         REPLICAS   IMAGE              PORTS
ph38i5su9slr   traefik_traefik       replicated   1/1        traefik:v2.4
yhu02cqufy8l   wordpress_db          replicated   1/1        mysql:5.7
v4q2ztqwv118   wordpress_wordpress   replicated   1/1        wordpress:latest

user@prod:~/wordpress$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED      STATUS      PORTS                                                                      NAMES
697cf6cfa806   traefik:v2.4   "/entrypoint.sh --pr…"   4 days ago   Up 4 days   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, :::443->443/tcp   traefik_traefik.1.i4txtjd2p0rcbnpd3bkv54eo2
```

Why are the wordpress containers not showing up in `docker ps -a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `Docker Swarm` which can run over multiple nodes in cluster mode.

A plausible scenario is that `traefik` is running on the node where you're executing the `docker ps -a` command and the other containers are running on different node/s.

To confirm that there is more than one node you can try and execute `docker node ls`. I can't think of any other scenario where you have a running service, but only one of the containers is visible (and you have a single host).

Comment: and this command: `docker node ps $(docker node ls -q)` should return to you all containers across all nodes.

Comment: I feel so embarrassed for not thinking about that and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You can also use 'docker stack ps <stackname>' to see where the app is running